# git and branch names

Tags: git, tags, git-branch

I am wanting to double check my work with git.

I am trying to use a remote repo server:
I want to only work on MYBRANCH, so I only clone MYBRANCH

```
/usr/local/git/bin/git clone -b MYBRANCH git@172.27.13.29:/home/PROJECT.git
```

when I run

```
git remote -v
```

I see

```
origin git@172.27.13.29:/home/PROJECT.git (fetch)
origin git@172.27.13.29:/home/PROJECT.git (push)
```

I expected to see MYBRANCH and not origin

Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`origin` is the name of the remote repository, not the name of a branch.

For instance, when you go to push changes back, you'll type `git push origin MYBRANCH` which says "push the local branch `MYBRANCH` to the remote repository `origin`'s branch `MYBRANCH`".

If you want to see remote branches, you should use `git branch -r` rather than `git remote -v`.

Comment: so am I actually getting the correct data out of the git remote with the -b MYBRANCH?

Comment: Yes. The command that you have stated is one that will clone the remote repository and check out the `MYBRANCH` branch.

Comment: and to push my changes back to MYBRANCH I have to use git push origin MYBRANCH?

Comment: You should be able to just `git push` if that's the only local branch you have. However, `git push origin MYBRANCH` is the "canonical" form that explicitly specifies all aspects.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote` shows you the remote repositories you're connected to.  And indeed, it's showing you exactly where you've cloned your repository (which is in your initial command):

`git@172.27.13.29:/home/PROJECT.git`

If you want to see the *branches*:

See *remote* branches: `git branch -r`

See *all* branches: `git branch -a`

See just your *local* branches: `git branch`

Comment: I understand that, I want to make sure that I got only the data, from the remote repo, from branch MYBRANCH. Am I doing that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

syntax for pushing and pulling is

git push/pull "remote name" "branch name"

in this case "remote name" is origin and "branch name" is MYBRANCH